Installing pot on FreeBSD: no such pool 'zroot'
According to the documentation of pot, the following has to be done to install it:
pkg install -y pot
pot init -v

I tried this, but ended up with the following error:
cannot create 'zroot/pot': no such pool 'zroot'
cannot create 'zroot/pot/bases': no such pool 'zroot'

I have not been able to find how to solve this issue online. Has anyone encounterd this and does anyone know how to fix it?
System info:
```                        `       
  ` `.....---.......--.```   -/    -------------
  +o   .--`         /y:`      +.   OS: FreeBSD 14.1-RELEASE-p4 amd64
   yo`:.            :o      `+-    Uptime: 20 hours, 30 mins
    y/               -/`   -o/     Packages: 88 (pkg)
   .-                  ::/sy+:.    Shell: sh
   /                     `--  /    Terminal: /dev/pts/0
  `:                          :`   CPU: AMD EPYC-Rome (1) @ 1.996GHz
  `:                          :`   GPU: 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI vgapci0@pci0:0:2:0: class=0x030000
   /                          /    Memory: 420MiB / 987MiB
   .-                        -.
    --                      -.
     `:`                  `:`
       .--             `--.
          .---.....----.

This is an instance running on Vultr.
Thank you

What does the ZFS setup look on your system? How have you configured this pot software?

Yes, please [edit] your post and add the output of zfs list.

@Kusalananda Turns out Vultr configured FreeBSD with ifs instead of zfs. My guess is that if I can change the filesystem to zfs this should work

@Jomy That sounds like a very reasonable guess. If you manage to move to a ZFS filesystem and get it working, you could post your own answer just to say what the cause of the issue was, and how you solved it.

Turns out Vultr configures Freebsd with ufs instead of zfs. After changing to zfs, the software worked.
See5 https://people.freebsd.org/~lidl/blog/re-root.html](https://people.freebsd.org/~lidl/blog/re-root.html) for changng the filesystem.

First see if there are any pools listed using this command (looking for zroot):
zpool list

If no (which is probably the reason), create a pool using:
zpool create zroot /dev/sda1

ATTENTION: replace sda1 with the actual volume you want to install the pool to. you can list the disks using sudo fdisk -l or lsblk
Then you can run the init command again:
pot init -v


Note that zroot is the default pool name for the root pool when FreeBSD is installed on a ZFS root filesystem.  If the zroot pool is missing, there's something very odd going on.  This answer does not solve the issue in the question.
